# Documentation/reference for fastboot

Tags: fastboot, documentation

Where can I find the documentation for `fastboot` in Android SDK's `platform-tools`?

I know that running `fastboot` on its own gives a quick help for the different commands, but I'd like to know about details such as:

- `update`: What does *update.zip* need to look like
- `flashall`: Where do the *flash boot + recovery + system* come from, what format, etc.
- `boot`: What is the format of `<kernel>` and what is the `<ramdisk>` option
- `flash:raw boot`: What is the difference to `boot` and what is it used for

I am surprised that in the [Android Developer's Tools Help](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html#) there is documentation for `adb` but not `fastboot`.

Comment: Any progress here? I'm wondering about flash:raw, too.

Answer (score 4):

Fastboot commandline utilisation as per [eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/Android_Fastboot#Commands) is shown below.

```
$ fastboot -h
usage: fastboot [ <option> ] <command>

commands:
  update <filename>                        reflash device from update.zip
  flashall                                 flash boot + recovery + system
  flash <partition> [ <filename> ]         write a file to a flash partition
  erase <partition>                        erase a flash partition
  getvar <variable>                        display a bootloader variable
  boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]              download and boot kernel
  flash:raw boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]    create bootimage and flash it
  devices                                  list all connected devices
  reboot                                   reboot device normally
  reboot-bootloader                        reboot device into bootloader

options:
  -w                                       erase userdata and cache
  -s <serial number>                       specify device serial number
  -p <product>                             specify product name
  -c <cmdline>                             override kernel commandline
  -i <vendor id>                           specify a custom USB vendor id
```

> `update`: What does *update.zip* need to look like

In general, `fastboot` flashes only `.img` files.

The *update.zip* generally consists of `.img` files which will be flashed to the particular partition. A typical  *update.zip* file to flash via `fastboot` will have following files and more

```
boot.img
recovery.img
system.img
userdata.img
radio.img
etc...
```

> `flashall`: Where do the *flash boot + recovery + system* come from, what
>   format, etc.

`flashall` will flash the `system.img`, `boot.img` & `recovery.img` in the current/PATH folder. These images can be obtained from the *update.zip* mentioned above.

> `boot`: What is the format of `<kernel>` and what is the `<ramdisk>` option

In `fastboot boot`, the `<kernel>` format is an `.img` file. I am not sure of the `<ramdisk>` option. My guess would be to boot a `kernel` with a modified `ramdisk` without altering the built `kernel` (I am not a developer, sorry).

This is what I have learnt fiddling with Nexus phones. Others can correct any obvious errors in the write up.